# Why must the "thousand years" of the Millennium be figurative and not literal?

Tags: revelation, figure-of-speech

A comment to this answer: [What is the Order of the Resurrection of the Dead - Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83213/what-is-the-order-of-the-resurrection-of-the-dead/83222#83222):

> This answer assumes a literal 1,000 years.
> The text of scripture is very clear in that the figure of 1,000 must be figurative.

What Biblical evidence is there to conclude this statement about the length of the Millennium?

CLARIFICATION:
by Millennium, I'm referring to the 1,000 year period described in Revelation.  My linked answer supposes this period to be the Kingdom of God on Earth, ruled by Jesus and his "siblings", who were resurrected or transformed into spirit beings at his return.
(But I think this doctrinal position is irrelevant to this question, which is about the clarity of the literal or figurative meaning of "thousand years".  It's the words "*clear*" and "*must*" that are most significant for this question.)

Comment: This is very divisive - I can cite many on both sides.  There is NOTHING to explicitly decide this question in the text.  It is a matter of opinion and interpretation.

Comment: *Must* is pretty strong - especially since some who knew the apostles believed it was quite literal (e.g. Papias of Hieropolis)

Comment: @RayButterworth This question seems, at first glance, to be a bit redundant grammatically, as though you are asking: "Why must the thousand years of the thousand years be figurative and not literal?" It's not my intention to interject confusion here; is your use of the word "Millennium" intended to simply imply 1,000, or rather to refer to the Millennium of *premillennial doctrine*?

Comment: Unfortunately, because the question was closed, I am not able now to provide you the Biblical answer you were looking for.  It's just a bit much to put into a comment, but the Biblical evidence for it being a literal period of time is strong--right from the book of Revelation itself.  Perhaps when the question reopens, you may remind me to provide an answer.  God bless.

Comment: @Polyhat, thanks, but note that I wasn't looking for support of the literal period of time, simply for confirmation of the absence of the the "very clear" support for a figurative interpretation that was claimed in the quotation.

Comment: I believe the 1,000 years is figurative. But the question cannot be worded in this way ('must'). And to discuss a closure, one should use Meta, not edit the question in order to respond to Moderation.

Comment: Rolled back to last good version - as Nigel has said, Meta is the appropriate place to discuss question closures

Comment: @NigelJ, what does "*in this way ('must')*" mean?  The word "must" is taken directly from your original claim.  What other way is there?

Comment: 'Original claim' ? I have no memory of an 'original claim'. Please clarify.

Comment: @NigelJ, In the linked question, you commented (my emphasis): "*This answer assumes a literal 1,000 years. The text of **scripture is very clear** in that the figure of 1,000 **must** be figurative. […] . – Nigel J May 13 at 21:39*". Rather than discuss it in comments there, I asked this question here in order to find out what that **very clear** text is and why it **must** be figurative. ¶ And I don't know what your '*But the question cannot be worded in this way ("must")*' comment above means.

Comment: Thank you for prompting my memory. Yes, figurative. And I can comment so. For a comment can be 'moderated' by  deleting it. But a question, not so. And an answer not so, either. There are procedures to follow. I am reading, again, [John Metcalfe's](https://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/) book _Revelation_ . It is far more erudite, studied, clear and  spiritual than I could ever express myself. All I can do is thoroughly recommend it. I first heard him expound it in the 1970s. And I follow his teaching on it to this day. I am reading the book again and am half way through it.

Answer (score 0):

### Why must the “thousand years” of Revelation be figurative and not literal?

**Answer**: With few exceptions, **the entire book is symbolic**. The number *1000 represents an indeterminate period of time.*

Let us examine verses 4 through 6 of Revelation 20 to try and understand why (these are some of those quoted in the OP's link):

> **Revelation 20:4-6**: "<sup>4</sup>Then I saw thrones, and they sat on them, and judgment was given to them. And I saw the souls of those who had been beheaded because of their testimony of Jesus and because of the word of God, and those who had not worshiped the beast or his image, and had not received the mark on their forehead and on their hand; and they came to life and reigned with Christ for a thousand years.
> <sup>5</sup>The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were completed. This is the first resurrection. <sup>6</sup>Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection; over these the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with Him for a thousand years."

First, we should recognize that the faithful are the ones seated on the thrones. They are given authority to judge the world (1 Cor. 6:3) just as Noah judged the world before the Flood, through our obedience to God. The “souls under the altar” (cf. Rev. 6:9) is merely the totality of saints that have suffered throughout history for the Word of God.

**NOTE**: **We, the faithful, are those suffering souls!** God's saints have been persecuted (some beheaded or worse) throughout history. Just who has not watched the evening news and put their head in their hands asking: "*How long Lord, before you avenge the injustices on the earth -- how long before it all ends?*" (cf. Rev. 6:10).

These same very words are recorded for us earlier in the same Book:

> **Revelation 6:10**: "[The voices of the faithful underneath the altar] cried out with a loud voice, saying, 'How long, O Lord, holy and true, will You refrain from judging and avenging our blood on those who dwell on the earth?'”

In verse 4 of chapter 20, the expression, "Coming to life and reigning with Christ for a thousand years" speaks to our spiritual birth, the Life we obtain in Christ. Prior to that time, we were considered **dead to God**:

> **Ephesians 2:1**: "And you were dead in your trespasses and sins."

Now, to paraphrase verse 5, "The rest of the dead [the faithless are dead in sin] did not come to life until the thousand years [an indeterminate period of time] were completed." The reality is that the faithless are not only dead in *this life*, they are spiritually dead in the next one.

As well, let us paraphrase verse 6 because its meaning is paramount to our understanding of Life through salvation:

> **Revelation 20:6 paraphrased**: “Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection [baptism into Christ]; over these [Christians], the second death [spiritual death] has no power, but they [Christians] will be priests of God and of Christ [all Christians are priests and royalty: 1 Peter 2:9] and will reign with Him for a thousand years [until Christ’s return].”

The “thousand years” in this passage, as the bracketed notation indicates, is used to symbolize the time that remains relative to the end of time, that is, the period before Christ brings the world to an end.

As the faithful, we are “priests of God and of Christ,” and we are “reigning with Him” now – just as all saints have, precisely as the passage from Revelation tells us. We read identical language in Peter's First Letter:

> **1 Peter 2:9**: "But you [Christians] are A CHOSEN RACE, A royal PRIESTHOOD, A HOLY NATION, A PEOPLE FOR God’s OWN POSSESSION..."

**For these and many other reasons, the 1,000 years of Revelation 20 *must be figurative.* It makes no sense, given that all the surrounding text is figurative, to argue that the number 1,000 alone is literal.**

Comment: "*given that all the surrounding text is figurative*" isn't obvious.  The paraphrase does supply a figurative meaning, but that doesn't prove that a figurative meaning was intended.  ¶Does this figurative meaning have a literal absolute beginning and end, or is it relative to each person? How does it fit in with Satan's being confined during this "thousand year" period?  Clearly he is not confined now.

Comment: @Ray To address your questions: 1) "Does the [meaning] have a [literal] beginning and end, or is it relative to each person?" You have actually hit the jackpot with this question. Christians *now* reign with Christ (1 Pet. 2:9). *We* are judging the world through our godly behavior (1 Cor. 6:2, Heb. 11:7). Satan's *authority over death* (of the saints) has been removed -- that is the binding or confinement. And, all saints are only as far from Christ's return as their physical death. That's why the 1000 years is indeterminate: it represents the time we each have left before we enter eternity.

Comment: @Xeno I notice that depending on which translation one is using, verses 4 and 5 may or may not have a paragraph division between them.  In KJV and NIV for example, there is no paragraph division, this is consistent with the saved being raised at the second coming of Christ, the wicked who are dead before the second coming do not see the second coming ( left in the grave at the second coming) rather they are raised at the time of the judgement after the 1000 years is passed.  However, in NLT and BSB for example, where there is a paragraph division, it could easily be read very differently.

Comment: @Adam Regarding the paragraph divisions between 4 and 5, I embedded that myself to break the passages up just a bit for legibility. But, yes, we are either saved or lost at the moment of our death, our lives having been judged against the Bible: **John 12:48b**: "[The] word I spoke is what will judge him at the last day." Our compliance to the Word is what judges us, and if we do not align ourselves with that Word **now**, we are "storing up wrath for ourselves in the Day of Wrath" (Rom. 2:5). The wicked, however, are immediately consigned to Hades upon death (Lk. 16:19ff). "1000" is symbolic.

Comment: @Xeno said "*we are either saved or lost at the moment of our death, our lives having been judged against the Bible*".  The Bible says "*Nor is there salvation in any other, for there is no other name under heaven given among men by which we must be saved.*" ([Acts 4:12](https://www.blueletterbible.org/nkjv/act/4/12/t_conc_1022012)). Does that mean that the billions of people that never even heard the name "Jesus", much less his (the Bible's) message, were created destined to never have a chance at salvation, and will be tortured forever? If so, that is a very sick God running the show.

Comment: @RayButterworth It's unclear to me what God has in store for those that have never heard. I'm  not in a position to answer that. I would hope God has an alternative to such circumstances. He has said: "I will have mercy on whom I will have mercy and compassion on whom I will have compassion" (Ex. 33:20). We might also understand  that whomever we ask irrespective of country, almost everyone is aware of Christ to some extent. As stated in Matthew 28:19 (paraphrasing): "[Missionaries have made] disciples of all the nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit."

Comment: @RayButterworth I did not realize this post was closed. I too have great difficulty asking questions because I'm still not quite sure how to ask them without their being closed or labeled duplicate. Nonetheless, I never down-voted your OP. Perhaps the use of the capitalized "Millennium" (thereby, perceived as espousing premillennialism) was at issue? I don't know.

Comment: I doubt it was closed because of premillennialism. The question is not about premillennialism. It is a valid church doctrine for some denominations and is very much biblical to those denominations. I also disagree entirely with the view that the 1000 years is not literal.  In terms of being saved or not however, i dont think concentrating on the finer points of this doctrine really matter. Jesus said, we are to treat our salvation like a thief in the night...that means always be ready and that is what is most important. The question isnt worded the right way to avoid opinion based answers.

Comment: I've always understood the "thousand years" to represent "all of the time"  however much time that may be.  Just like "the cattle on a thousand hills belong to the Lord" doesn't mean that the 1001st cow belongs to someone else.

Comment: @Mike All the faithful are ~70 or so years (a lifetime) from stepping across the threshold of this world of time into the timelessness of God upon physical demise. Once you have stepped across that threshold (as far as ***you*** are concerned) all time on earth has already elapsed. You have effectively stepped to "the end of time." But to all others that remain "in time" they must "wait" until their own "last day." It is this unknown timespan that the "thousand years" represents. Christ could not answer "when" this would occur because it occurs to everyone indistinguishably from one another.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is going to depend on the eschatological ‘camp’ you have your feet in. Some views require it to figurative, some others can accommodate a literal 1000yrs.

You asked ...”*What Biblical evidence is there to conclude this statement about the length of the Millennium?*”.

You need to understand that **both** [any] views will have, and do have their scriptural support. So my contention is that this [quoting verses] alone probably won’t ‘sway’ you. We perhaps need to look for the answer by considering what the 1000 yrs is needed for - and this should help us answer whether this period is literal or figurative.

For those who argue that this 1000yrs is literal, it’s all about Israel. Israel was promised a Messiah - one who would sit on the throne of David - and rule.

**LUKE 1: 32** *He will be great, and will be called the Son of the Highest; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David*

Has this happened? I’m aware some say yes, - [they say] figuratively Jesus is sitting on the throne ‘in heaven’. So they don’t need the 1000yrs for this - so where to ‘fit’ them? One solution is to say that period is symbolic, figurative.

But others say no, this [Jesus sitting on the throne in Jerusalem] has yet to happen. And it’s here that this ‘1000’ year reign ‘hinges’. The literalists say this is the time period during which Jesus sits on the throne in Jerusalem, during the Millennium, where as the ‘figurative’ ‘camp’ don’t need this.

The point is, your ‘view’ on whether this 1000 years is literal or figurative is not going  come via specific ‘scripture’. Both will be able to argue their case ‘using’ scripture. The actual ‘foundation’ for your view on this depends on your view of the role of Israel. Or, in a wider sense, your eschatological view - and as Dottard said, “*This is very divisive*’.

And forgive me for constantly repeating this, all ‘sides’ will be able to ‘pull’/quote scripture to supposedly support their view.

It’s one of those questions that can really only be answered by taking a broader view of ‘the whole picture’, rather than focusing on or using a specific’verse’ as ‘proof’. So the ‘verses’ you need are the ones supporting ‘the bigger picture’. Then the 1000 years will easily fall into place, and the answer to ‘literal’ or ‘figurative’ will be answered.(for you).

Comment: Dave, you begin your Answer by saying "You need to understand that **both** views will, and do find scriptural support". In the last paragraph, after suggesting to take "a broader view of ‘the whole picture’", you conclude that "the 1000 years will easily fall into place" and "the answer to ‘literal’ or ‘figurative’ will be answered". Apparently not only beauty, but even truth is in "in the eye of the beholder" ...

Comment: I agree that various denominations "*will be able to ‘pull’/quote scripture to supposedly support their view*".  But my question isn't about *support*, it's with respect to the claim that "*scripture is very clear*" and "*must be figurative*".  The person that made this statement has a high reputation in both BH.SE and C.SE, so I was trying to find out what these clear scriptures were.

Comment: @Ray Butterworth Appreciate you clarifying the motivation for the question. My response was for consideration.As you can see, I don’t actually answer the *specific* “Literal or Figurative” question - but hopefully show a possible path to that answer. Nevertheless I now see what you were actually seeking.

Comment: @Miguel de Servet “*Apparently not only beauty, but even truth is in ‘in the eye of the beholder’*”. - A very perceptive comment - one that IMHO actually has a lot ‘right’ about it. Cheers!

Comment: Dave, you call my comment “perceptive”. I was referring sarcastically to the obvious (unstated) conclusion of your Answer ...

Comment: @Miguel de Servet Yes, I know! You meant it as ‘sarcastic’, but your sarcasm has some ‘truth’ to it. Because what ‘truth’ is differs for different people. People can be looking at the same ‘verses’, (at the same ‘thing’) yet nevertheless have a completely different view/understanding of them. That was actually my point. As you say - It depends on the eyes of the beholder. But, if you ‘step back’, you will ‘see’ more, and your ‘view’ [might] change!

Comment: Dave, would you dare to go as far as saying that God, at least, knows / will decide **unambiguously** whether the answer is / will be ‘literal’ or ‘figurative’?

Comment: @Miguel de Servet without doubt, God has already decreed (determined) this. And, through prophecy, has already told us. It’s just that many can’t see it yet. His word is truth.

Comment: Dave, I wrote "God knows / will decide" for a reason: I believe that in this, like in other ambiguous cases, it is more a matter of God's Omnipotence than of Omniscience.